# specs2 xml matcher with mockito

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

XmlMatchers are very powerful, but i'm not able to use it as argument matcher. How can i modify the matcher to be not for Seq[Node]?

```
  trait Connector {
      def send(envelope: Node):Elem    
  }
```

Write a test with scalatest, using mockito and xmlMatchers traits:

```
import org.scalatest.junit.AssertionsForJUnit
import org.junit.Test
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import scala.xml.Node
import org.specs2.matcher.ThrownExpectations
import org.specs2.matcher.XmlMatchers

class MyClientTest extends AssertionsForJUnit with Mockito with ThrownExpectations with XmlMatchers {

      @Test def oclQuery_oclExpression_queryRequestWithOclElement {
        //arrange
        val connector=mock[Connector]
        val testee=MyClient.create(connector)    
        //act
        testee.oclQuery("oclexpr", <Response/> )
        //assert
        there was one(connector).send( argThat(\\("ocl")) )
      }

    }
```

compile error: type mismatch;  found   : Seq[scala.xml.Node]  required: scala.xml.Node

How can i convert the XmlMatcher for \("ocl") to a single node, so the argThat can match the required Node argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "adapt" the matcher to take the argument type:

`there was one(connector).send(argThat(\\("ocl") ^^ ((_:Node).toSeq)))`